# Bicycle crank conversion

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset

So I have this crank that I want to convert. It has three crankwheels and I don't expect myself to ride on the two of them. I have found a second hand crankwheel from a friend that I want to put on so that my life gets easier but I need the "plates" or I don't know how they are called to come off. As I can see there is a bolt for a hex but when I put it in to turn it and remove it, it does nothing. From the back side of it, it seems to be a rivet. Ps. I don't have enough money for a new crankset if this is what you are suggesting. I just need the crankwheels to come off.[image]

Comment: So you have a triple front crank and want to change to a single chainring?  Can you post a photo of your replacement chainring?   Remember depending on toothcount, you will loose the highest and lowest gears.

Comment: Bacically I don't really care about the big and the small chainring but only the middle one. I have got some trouble posting photos in the first place, but I will try again. Because I don't own the replacement chainring as yet but I will only buy it from a friend after I have successfully removed all the chainrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove the granny gear (the little one) and try running on a double for a while.

If the chainrings are rivetted together then you'll need a drill, and reverting  will be impossible.

If they're bolted on with chainring bolts you need a special spanner, as per   [How can one remove this chainring?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45304/how-can-one-remove-this-chainring)

If you remove the bigger chainring, there will only be the middle ring left, so no need to buy the replacement chainring.

There's a chance you can remove the front derailleur, but it might still be needed as a chain guide to stop the chain jumping off.  Don't trash it when removing.

Comment: If I remove the rivets can I then put on new crainring bolts?